# what is linux kernel module dm_bio_prison?

Tags: kernel-modules, device-mapper

A kernel module name `dm_bio_prison` and descripted with "device-mapper bio prison" is loaded on a linux system. It is used by the modules `dm_cache` and `dm_thin_pool`.

```
#lsmod  | grep dm_bio_prison
dm_bio_prison          20480  2 dm_thin_pool,dm_cache
```

https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/linux/kernel/3.7/dm-bio-prison_8h.html shows that
some functinality would be related to "limit"/"detain"/"restrict". I seek information about what function this module provides

Comment: Maybe this is helpful? https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/md/dm-bio-prison-v2.h where `bio` is like a portmanteau(?) of Block I/O. This comment in particular: 
`Sometimes we can't deal with a bio straight away.  We put them in prison where they can't cause any mischief.  Bios are put in a cell identified by a key, multiple bios can be in the same cell.  When the cell is subsequently unlocked the bios become available.` Maybe `bio.h` makes things clearer as well: http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/kerneldevelopment/0672327201/ch13lev1sec3.html